# How to fill a variable in form A while in form B?

Tags: c#, forms

I have a project, where a wizard form is called to make a project. On the end of the wizard I want to send a 'world' object back to a variable in the Main form. But If I give the main form with it through the constructor I can't access it's methods or properties. Am I doing something wrong?

here is my code:

main form

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.NewProject();
}

private void NewProject()
{
    var myForm = new ProjectWizard(this);
    myForm.Show();
}
```

Wizard form code:

```
public ProjectWizard(Form form)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainForm = form;
}

private void finishButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //World world = new World();
    //MainForm.CurrentWorld = world;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you send the excat form class e.g. `MyForm` or `Form1` - not just the `Form` class

Comment: cant you make a public property and ShowDialog() then retrieve that property value on dialogresult.ok ?

Comment: Don't I do that with the this keyword? Or am I mistaking?

Comment: @RobinDashWood look at Michael's update - he explains it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make `CurrentWorld` `public` or `internal` on the `MainForm` class. Honestly, you're doing everything else right!

**UPDATE:** also make sure that the `MainForm` private field declared in `Form1` is of the type `MainForm` and not just `Form`. So, change the constructor a tidge too:

```
public ProjectWizard(MainForm form)
```

Comment: It is a public property.

Comment: Then make sure the private field named `MainForm` is of the type `MainForm` and not just `Form`. Keep in mind that the `MainForm` class bases `Form`, but it is its own type.

Comment: @RobinDashWood, I'm glad I could be of assistance! Please consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: I was, but I had to wait a few minutes it said, marked it now .